# When I import socket variable from another file, the websocket does not work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, create-react-app

Situation1.

```js
const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/socket");

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("socket: ", socket);
}, 3000);
```

It's work fine. readyState: **1**
[image]

Situation2.

```js
// test.js
export const socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3000/socket");
```

```js
import { socket } from "./test";

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("socket: ", socket);
}, 3000);
```

It's doesn't work. readyState: **0** and never change.

[image]

Does anyone know why? Is my computer broken? I spent almost all day because of this. Help me, please.

Comment: What build tool are you using, and what does the WebSocket request in the `Network` tab say?

Comment: I am using create-react-app. The websocket request status is pendding.

Answer (score 0):

Just add .js to path after test,`import { socket } from "./test.js";`

Change your code:

```
import { socket } from "./test";
import { socket } from "./test.js";
```